# How to implement SQLCipher when using SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to secure some sensible data by implementing encryption in my already existing and functioning database setup in an android application.

I tried to follow this tutorial (http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/) and I browsed a lot of foruns, including the google group for Cipher. However, I still don't clearly understand how does SQLCipher work and how I should adapt my code to serve my needs.

I am following this implementation of databases in android: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/#databasetutorial_database, meaning I have an extension of the SQLiteOpenHelper class and another class to store CRUD methods.

In this situation how should I use SQLCipher? Where should I define the password? Where should I use loadLibs(context)? Only in the main activity? Or in every activity that accesses the database?

I feel I'm almost there, I just need the final push to figure this out :P
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Where should I define the password?" - Very good question, the sqlcipher helper creates the db but doesnt seem to have any paramter or anything for password. Got the same issue atm.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*In this situation how should I use SQLCipher?*

**Exactly like an normal your normal sql implementation.**

*Where should I define the password?*

**If you are using SQLiteHelper it will create the database when you first get it like this:**

```
helper.getWriteableDatabase("myPassword");
```

**On the first call it will create the database with this Password. On the upcoing calls it will only work with this password.**

( Figured that out when i went to the Source: https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/blob/master/android-database-sqlcipher/src/main/java/net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteOpenHelper.java, checkout the method getWriteableDatabase( String pw )
 there! )

*Where should I use loadLibs(context)?*

**Right before you call** `helper.getWriteableDatabase("myPassword");` **the first time!**

Comment: How do we handle app upgrade from plain Content Provider to Encrypted Content provider (using SQLCipher)? My app crashes when I try to upgrade the app with these changes.

Answer (score 3):

> In this situation how should I use SQLCipher?

That is impossible to answer in the abstract. You would use it largely the same way that you use SQLite.

> Where should I define the password?

You should get it from the user.

> Where should I use loadLibs(context)? Only in the main activity? Or in every activity that accesses the database?

Once per process is sufficient (in fact, more could conceivably be a problem). If you are using a `ContentProvider` for your SQLCipher database, call `loadLibs()` in `onCreate()` of the `ContentProvider`. If you are using a custom `Application`, call `loadLibs()` in `onCreate()` of the `Application`.

Comment: "That is impossible to answer in the abstract. You would use it largely the same way that you use SQLite."

I am asking how to integrate it with SQLiteOpenHelper, not in abstract. But thanks for the rest.

Comment: @JZweige: SQLCipher for Android has its own `SQLiteOpenHelper` replacement. You would use it largely the same way that you use the `SQLiteOpenHelper` that is part of standard Android.

Comment: So you're saying that the only thing I need to do is to replace the imports and add loadLibs()? Interesting going to try that and do some tests, I'll see how it goes.

Comment: @JZweige: "So you're saying that the only thing I need to do is to replace the imports and add loadLibs()?" -- you will also need to collect a password from the user and use that when you call `getReadabaleDatabase()` and `getWritableDatabase()`. Otherwise, yes, it's pretty much a drop-in replacement.

Comment: How do we handle app upgrade from plain Content Provider to Encrypted Content provider (using SQLCipher)? My app crashes when I try to upgrade the app with these changes. Fresh install with encryption works good.

Comment: @Kaps: "My app crashes when I try to upgrade the app with these changes" -- then ask a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you provide the Java stack trace associated with the crash, along with the Java code that generates that crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Have done that, but not getting any resolution from folks, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897615/upgrading-plain-content-provider-databacked-by-sqlite-to-encrypted-using-sqlci