# Android Data Cipher Can't open File path

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption

I am trying to add a cipher to my apps.
I am using the cipher sample from https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher.
I am also following the advice from [How to implement SQLCipher when using SQLiteOpenHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754283/how-to-implement-sqlcipher-when-using-sqliteopenhelper)..

My app crashes. I have the database in my storage folder but it shows not path found and couldn't open the database.

```
 SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);

 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase("myPassword");
```

I thought adding this line it should work but it still crashed.

This is the error:

```
 03-03 17:42:06.409  17124-17137/? E/dalvikvm﹕ dlopen("/data/app-lib/GmsCore/libgmscore.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/GmsCore/libgmscore.so" not found

 03-03 17:42:06.409  17124-17137/? E/ProviderInstaller﹕ Unable to load native code from /data/app-lib/GmsCore/libgmscore.so

 03-03 17:42:06.429  17124-17147/? E/Babel﹕ canonicalizeMccMnc: invalid mccmnc

 03-03 17:42:06.439  17124-17147/? E/Babel﹕ canonicalizeMccMnc: invalid mccmnc nullnull

 03-03 17:42:06.439  17124-17137/? E/dalvikvm﹕ dlopen("/data/app-lib/GmsCore/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/GmsCore/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so" not found

 03-03 17:42:06.439  17124-17137/? E/ProviderInstaller﹕ Unable to load native code from /data/app-lib/GmsCore/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so

 03-03 17:42:30.262  16834-16834/? E/Database﹕ Error copying icu data file
java.io.FileNotFoundException: icudt46l.zip
```

Comment: One of the JNI libraries failed to load:`libgmscore.so`. Ensure native libs are being packaged properly to apk.

Comment: @S.D. thanks for the comment. from the lib itself i don't have the file.. u have any idea how to implement data cipher to an apps?